# How to prove if $P(B|A)<P(B)$ then $P(A|B)>P(A)$

Tags: probability

$$\text{If }P(B|A)<P(B) \text{ then, } P(A|B)>P(A)$$

This is what I have [Assuming it's true]

1. $P(B|A) < P(B) \implies P(A\text{ and } B) < P(A) \cdot P(B)$
2. $P(A|B) \cdot P(B) < P(A) \cdot P(B)$

This would give me $P(A|B) < P(A)$ but not the other way around. Is this relationship false or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @DavidMitra I think that was supposed to be => in the middle, not =.

Comment: @tabstop Ah, of course...

Comment: So yes, your argument is fine; the given statement has a typo.

Comment: The problem stated in the title is not the same as the problem stated in the body of the question.

Comment: Made a quick fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bayes' theorem: For events A and B, provided that P(B) ≠ 0, we have $P(A|B) = \frac{P(B | A)\, P(A)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(B | A)\,}{P(B)}  P(A) $

$(P(B|A)<P(B)) \wedge (P(B)>0) \implies \frac{P(B | A)\,}{P(B)} \, < 1$, therefore  $P(A|B) = \frac{P(B | A)\,}{P(B)}  P(A) <P(A)$.

Comment: You lost me at "implies P(B|A)/P(B) < 1 since P(B)>1, therefore P(A|B)<P(A). Probability cannot be greater than 1?

Comment: Sorry I meant $P(B)>0$.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your solution. I'm not seeing these relationships clearly.

Comment: @user121449 Better to see it this way, I think, by writing   $$P(B)>P(B\mid A)={P(A\mid B)P(B)\over P(A)}.$$ Then divide by $P(B)$ and multiply by $P(A)$.

Comment: @user121449 I added some details, hope it helps!

Comment: Is the solution identical to P(A|B)>P(A)? It seems like you did it the other way around

Comment: @DavidMitra that would give me P(A|B)<P(A) instead of P(A|B)>P(A)

Comment: @user121449 Yes. $P(A)>P(A\mid B)$ is the correct result.

Comment: @DavidMitra What I'm trying to prove is P(A|B)>P(A)

Comment: @user121449 I should have been more explicit: **That result is false; your problem source made a typo.**  Your solution to the correct statement is fine.  (As is this answer.)